# Android Studio DisplayMessageAcivity.java error

Tags: java, android-studio

[Screenshot on Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3DgJ.png)

Please, I really need your help. I'm just a beginner using the android studio and I'm kinda stuck somewhere. I have followed all the instructions properly but I'm having a problem importing the missing class to the `String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);`.
 I really need your help on this. I can't proceed any further with this tutorial because I keep getting error messages on Android Studio.

Comment: Kindly add Screenshot of error in your question so we would help more appropriately.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3DgJ.png

Comment: Can you tell us the link/document of tutorial you follow? I think you just forget to define `EXTRA_MESSAGE`

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm just new here @malioboro. Here is the link to the tutorial which I follow. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Its already answered, try to read the following links: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481408/android-first-application-string-cannot-be-resolved-or-is-not-a-field-error

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38758391/android-error-on-tutorial-cannot-find-symbol-variable-activity-display-message

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15338769/issues-with-creating-new-android-mainactivity

Comment: Thanks, @Tehmina. My problem seems to be solved.